# AMP query_param substitution in anchor tag for AMP HTML pages

Tags: amp-html

AMP docs that state I should be able to use QUERY_PARAMS inside my href tag.

My base url is:

```
http://localhost:3000/lp/test?amp=true?c=hello
```

My anchor tag is as follows:

```
<a href="http://localhost:3000/lp/test?amp=true?test=QUERY_PARAM(c)"></a>
```

With this in mind, I expect `QUERY_PARAM(c)` to be replaced with `hello` unless I interpreted the docs incorrectly. However, when I try to inspect the anchor tag on my page, the url comes out exactly as how it was before.

Expectation:

```
<a href="http://localhost:3000/lp/test?amp=true?test=QUERY_PARAM(c)" data-amp-replace="QUERY_PARAM"></a>
```

Actual:

```
<a href="http://localhost:3000/lp/test?amp=true?test=QUERY_PARAM(c)" data-amp-replace="QUERY_PARAM"></a>
```

When I click on the link, the url changes to the following. It seems like it's the not grabbing the query parameter

```
http://localhost:3000/lp/test?amp=true?test=
```

Comment: http://localhost:3000/lp/test?amp=true?c=hello is not a valid URL, this is a valid http://localhost:3000/lp/test?amp=true&c=hello. There can only be ONE `?` for query parameters, rest should be `&`

Comment: @adnanyousafch thanks!! such a silly mistake.